# Bootstrap 4 third level child menu not on the right side

Tags: css, wordpress, bootstrap-4, menu

I'm using the following Bootstrap 4 theme in Wordpress: https://cutt.ly/QfzDnKv
I'm using the Bootstrap 4 navbar with third level child menu's which is not by Bootstrap 4 defaults supported. That's why I used this custom CSS in Bootstrap 4:

https://www.codeply.com/go/ji5ijk6yJ4

```css
.navbar-nav li:hover > ul.dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
}
.dropdown-submenu {
    position:relative;
}
.dropdown-submenu>.dropdown-menu {
    top: 0;
    left: 100%;
    margin-top:-6px;
}

/* rotate caret on hover */
.dropdown-menu > li > a:hover:after {
    text-decoration: underline;
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
```

I have now a situation that my child menu's will be shown up on the bottom of each parent menu:

[image: example]

In the example above Exact needs to show up on the right side of the parent menu (like the codeply example). Could anyone tell me what I have to adjust in order to let it show up the correct way? I'm struggling already 1 week with this.

Thanks!

grid

Comment: can you share full code with HTML

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```css
.navbar-nav li:hover > ul.dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
}
.dropdown-submenu {
    position:relative;
}
.dropdown-submenu>.dropdown-menu {
    top: 0;
    left: 100%;
    margin-top:-6px;
}

/* rotate caret on hover */
.dropdown-menu > li > a:hover:after {
    text-decoration: underline;
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light">
    <div class="navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="http://example.com" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"> Dropdown </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown-submenu"><a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" href="http://google.com">Google</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Submenu</a></li>
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Submenu0</a></li>
                            <li class="dropdown-submenu"><a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" href="#">Submenu 1</a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Subsubmenu1</a></li>
                                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Subsubmenu1</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li class="dropdown-submenu"><a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" href="#">Submenu 2</a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Subsubmenu2</a></li>
                                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Subsubmenu2</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow because they don't explain how it solves the problem. If you edit your answer to explain what this code does and how it answers the question, it would make it more useful to the OP as well as other users with similar issues.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this actually by using the answer of Bhautik. I tried his code line by line and came to the conclusion that the following CSS could be used:

```
.dropdown-submenu>.dropdown-menu {
    top: 0;
    left: 100%;
    margin-top:-6px;
}
```

Thanks,

Have a nice day.